# ORM filter pattern

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, peewee

I'm trying to dissect the pattern used in most Python ORMs, but the source code for the ones I've looked through are a little difficult to grok.

How do ORMs structure their `Model`, `Field`, and `Query` classes such that statements passed to a  `.filter()` class method are deferred?

I attempted to codify my question, hopefully this makes it easier to understand (see the comments in `main()`.

```
class YuckORM:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = [
            File('https://cdn.fake/doc.pdf', 1000),
            File('https://cdn.fake/song.mp3', 2000),
            File('https://cdn.fake/video.mp4', 3000),
        ]

    def query(self):
        return Query(self.files)


class Query:
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files

    def filter(self, **args):
        files = []
        # do filtering somehow?
        return Query(files)

    def all(self):
        return self.files


class Field:
    def _init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class File:
    url = Field('url')
    size = Field('size')

    def __init__(self, url, size):
        self.url = url
        self.size = size


def main():
    yorm = YuckORM()
    all_the_things = yorm.query.all()  # this part is easy
    # this is where I'm confused.
    some_of_them = yorm.query.filter(File.size > 1000).all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peewee uses data-structures to represent things. Models, fields, expressions, queries, etc. When you pass these data-structures to be executed, they are converted into SQL and then returned as a database cursor. Then there is separate logic which reconstructs the flat row-tuples returned by the cursor into the appropriate model instances.

The peewee code-base is pretty small, ~5000 lines -- should give you an idea. Take a look at the 3.0a branch as it's a lot easier to read. https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3.0a/peewee.py

For more stripped-down "query-builder" library code, you might check out: https://github.com/coleifer/sweepea/blob/master/sweepea.pyx#L1964-L3116 -- it's Cython but should be easy enough to make sense of.

Comment: While I was at originally unsatisfied with this answer, the peewee 3.0a  was actually exactly want I needed! Thanks a lot!